# What is Intl library in Dart for?

Tags: dart

I read API documents of intl library, but I realy don't have any idea what Intl class helps us.

At first, I have been thinking that the library is like ResourceBundle class in Java.

But now, I can't say for sure...

When should I use intl library?
or Are there any good samples about the library?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [intl example](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fbleeding_edge%2Fdart%2Fpkg%2Fintl%2Fexample%2Fbasic) in the source code.

From the example comments:

> This defines messages for an English locale directly in the program
>   and has separate libraries that define German and Thai messages
>   that say more or  less the same thing, and prints the message with
>   the date and time in it formatted appropriately for the locale.

The German file defines a `runAt` message, which takes two args: `time` and `day`

```dart
runAt(time, day) => 
  Intl.message('Ausgedruckt am $time am $day.', name: 'runAt', args: [time, day]);
```

The [basic_example.dart](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/pkg/intl/example/basic/basic_example.dart) defines the default, English version

```dart
runAt(time, date) => 
   Intl.message('Ran at $time on $day', name: 'runAt', args: [time, day]);
```

You can then use the correct locale:

```dart
var de = new Intl('de_DE');
Intl.withLocale(de.locale, () => runAt('10:00', 'Dienstag')).then(print);
// default (en_GB?) locale
Intl.withLocale(new Intl().locale, () => runAt('10:00', 'Tuesday')).then(print);
```

(`print` is the default `print()` function to output the message).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, I don't understand the library yet. 
I try the [intl example](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fbleeding_edge%2Fdart%2Fpkg%2Fintl%2Fexample%2Fbasic) , then I got an error below.
'NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'then''

Comment: It should work, and in the tests you can find intl_message_basic_example_test.dart which runs it. In addition to allowing message substitution, it also formats dates and numbers (dates work right now, numbers don't really work yet).

Comment: It doesn't work:(   　 
See [intl example](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/pkg/intl/example/basic/basic_example.dart).　
In basic_example.dart:line 55, 'runAt' function is returning a string.
The function reference is passed to 'printForLocale' function.　
In 'printForLocale', the function as 'operation' is called and would be return a string. String class doesn't have 'then' method, so I get an NoSuchMethodError.
　
I found another error in check mode, so I can't believe this sample...